# 難読化されたjsに関して、使用ツールの特定と復元方法について

Tags: javascript

以下のように難読化されたjsのコードがあります。

```
zSbTF_sh = 26496;
bas_sh = Math.floor((7 & 5) * (33 | 0x0f) * (11 ^ 0x5b) / (23 << 3) * Math.sqrt(23 >> 3)) * (29 | 82) - Math.pow(11, 3);
Bas_sh = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mac") != -1 ? Math.ceil((7 << 2) * (9 | 4) / (0x0b & 7)) - (10 ^ 2) : (7 << 4) + (10 >> 2);
sfc_sh = String.fromCharCode;

function Sf_sh() {
    var ht = "", nu, i;
    for (i = 0; i < Sf_sh.arguments.length; i++) {
        nu = eval(Bas_sh + Sf_sh.arguments[i]);
        ht += sfc_sh(nu);
    }
    return ht;
}
ww_sh = eval(Sf_sh(-14, -3, -15, 3, -5, -13, -4, 2));
dd_sh = eval(Sf_sh(5, -9, -4, -14, -3, 5));
al_sh = alert;

function sf_sh() {
    var ht = "", nu, i;
    for (i = 0; i < sf_sh.arguments.length; i++) {
        nu = eval(bas_sh + sf_sh.arguments[i]);
        ht += sfc_sh(nu);
    }
    return ht;
}
```

このコードに関して、何のツールを使って難読化処理がされたのかを
特定することは可能でしょうか？
また、ある程度見やすい形に復元することは可能でしょうか？

どなたかわかる方いらっしゃいましたら、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 6):

該当のソースコードは [SHTML](http://shtml.jp/) という Windows 用のソフトウェアを使って難読化されています。 体験版を使い、JS Encoder > エキスパートモード（？）でソースコードを変換すると、質問で挙げられたものとそっくりの出力が得られます。

*Original*:

```js
window.alert("Hello");
```

*Converted*:

```js
diOLa_sh = 19054;
bas_sh = Math.ceil((0x27 << 5) * Math.E * Math.LN10 * Math.PI / 2) + (17 ^ 7) * (5 | 7);
Bas_sh = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mac") != -1 ? Math.ceil((7 << 2) * (9 | 4) / (0x0b & 7)) - (10 ^ 2) : (7 << 4) + (10 >> 2);
sfc_sh = String.fromCharCode;
 
function Sf_sh() {
    var ht = "",
        nu, i;
    for (i = 0; i < Sf_sh.arguments.length; i++) {
        nu = eval(Bas_sh + Sf_sh.arguments[i]);
        ht += sfc_sh(nu);
    }
    return ht;
}
ww_sh = eval(Sf_sh(-14, -3, -15, 3, -5, -13, -4, 2));
dd_sh = eval(Sf_sh(5, -9, -4, -14, -3, 5));
al_sh = alert;
 
function sf_sh() {
    var ht = "",
        nu, i;
    for (i = 0; i < sf_sh.arguments.length; i++) {
        nu = eval(bas_sh + sf_sh.arguments[i]);
        ht += sfc_sh(nu);
    }
    return ht;
}
m1x26767_sh = Sf_sh(-42, -13, -6, -6, -3);
dd_sh.alert(m1x26767_sh);
```

変数名の末尾 `_sh` は、SHTML の略称でしょうね。解説記事らしきものもありました。ドメイン所有者が同じことから、これも制作者の書いた SEO 用の宣伝記事だと思われます。

- [JavaScript難読化処理のためのヒント [9．String.fromCharCodeメソッドを少し変形させる]](http://www.broadband-xp.com/obfuscation/string.html)

しかし、この程度の暗号化は子供だましにしかなりません。専用のツールを使っても良いですが、解読には Chrome の Dev Tool で足りると思います。ソースコードの最後に、

```
debugger;
```

を追加して、該当の JavaScript を読み込ませるでもよいし。質問に書かれた部分だけに対しては、以下のようにしてから、自分で置き換えても良いでしょう。

```js
diOLa_sh = 19054;
bas_sh = Math.ceil((0x27 << 5) * Math.E * Math.LN10 * Math.PI / 2) + (17 ^ 7) * (5 | 7);
Bas_sh = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mac") != -1 ? Math.ceil((7 << 2) * (9 | 4) / (0x0b & 7)) - (10 ^ 2) : (7 << 4) + (10 >> 2);
sfc_sh = String.fromCharCode;
 
vars_buf = ""; // ■ 追加分

function Sf_sh() {
    var ht = "",
        nu, i;
    for (i = 0; i < Sf_sh.arguments.length; i++) {
        nu = eval(Bas_sh + Sf_sh.arguments[i]);
        ht += sfc_sh(nu);
    }
    vars_buf += "Sf_sh(" + Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) + ") = \"" + ht + "\"\n"; // ■ 追加分
    return ht;
}
ww_sh = eval(Sf_sh(-14, -3, -15, 3, -5, -13, -4, 2));
dd_sh = eval(Sf_sh(5, -9, -4, -14, -3, 5));
al_sh = alert;
 
function sf_sh() {
    var ht = "",
        nu, i;
    for (i = 0; i < sf_sh.arguments.length; i++) {
        nu = eval(bas_sh + sf_sh.arguments[i]);
        ht += sfc_sh(nu);
    }
    vars_buf += "sf_sh(" + Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) + ") = \"" + ht + "\"\n"; // ■ 追加分
    return ht;
}
m1x26767_sh = Sf_sh(-42, -13, -6, -6, -3);
dd_sh.alert(m1x26767_sh);

alert(vars_buf); // ■ 追加分
```

Answer (score 4):

難読化ツールは分からないですが、この手の圧縮を目的としていない難読化の解読は実行してみるのが手っ取り早いです。

質問のコードを上から見ていくと

> bas_sh = Math.floor((7 & 5) * (33 | 0x0f) * (11 ^ 0x5b) / (23 << 3) * Math.sqrt(23 >> 3)) * (29 | 82) - Math.pow(11, 3);

これには変数が入っていませんので定数に直せます。実行結果は`12349`でした。

> Bas_sh = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mac") != -1 ? Math.ceil((7 << 2) * (9 | 4) / (0x0b & 7)) - (10 ^ 2) : (7 << 4) + (10 >> 2);

これは三項演算子が入っているので別々に評価すると、`Math.ceil((7 << 2) * (9 | 4) / (0x0b & 7)) - (10 ^ 2)`も`(7 << 4) + (10 >> 2)`も`114`となることが分かります。なので`navigator.userAgent`はダミーです。

最後に以下の関数です。

```
function Sf_sh() {
    var ht = "", nu, i;
    for (i = 0; i < Sf_sh.arguments.length; i++) {
        nu = eval(Bas_sh + Sf_sh.arguments[i]);
        ht += sfc_sh(nu);
    }
    return ht;
}

ww_sh = eval(Sf_sh(-14, -3, -15, 3, -5, -13, -4, 2));
```

途中で`eval`を使用していますが、`Bas_sh`も`Sf_sh`の引数も数値であるためこれはダミーです。
次の`ht`の初期値は""なので、`sfc_sh`つまり`String.fromCharCode`で一文字ずつ文字列を追加する関数と判断できます。

なので実際に実行してみると`Sf_sh(-14, -3, -15, 3, -5, -13, -4, 2)`は"document"、`Sf_sh(5, -9, -4, -14, -3, 5)`は"window"となることが分かります。つまり最終的には

```
ww_sh = document;
dd_sh = window;
al_sh = alert;
```

というコードだと分かります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。実行して見ると色々と分かるのですね。また、ダミーも埋め込まれているとは分かりませんでした。
ただ、上記のようなコードが大量にあるので、一つ一つ実行して確認していくのは中々難しそうです・・・

Comment: @taktech 手作業でやるとどうしても各`eval`の中身を評価してやる必要がありますね。`Math`云々は今回の場合飛ばしてやっても良かったわけですが。

Answer (score 2):

FirebugやFirefoxDeveloperEdition等を使えば多少分かるかもしれません。

Firebug
[image: Firebug]

FirefoxDeveloperEdition
[image: FirefoxDeveloperEdition]

Answer (score 2):

ita_3yさんのコメントに書くべきなのでしょうが・・・  
改行できないと辛いので解答欄に書きます。

1・Firebugのスクリプトタブにある「すべて」のリスト部分を「評価スクリプトを表示」を含むものを選ぶ。  
2・すぐ右のjsリストから対象のevalを選ぶ。  
3・表示されたJSを整形ツールで整形する。

これでだいたい解読出来ると思います。

参考  
http://code.xenophy.com/?p=868

整形ツール例  
http://www.enjoyxstudy.com/misc/20060911/code_paste.html

他に使ったことはないですが、「Caffeine Monkey」という手段も有ります。  
Caffeine Monkey  
http://www.secureworks.com/cyber-threat-intelligence/tools/caffeinemonkey/
解説サイト  
http://kinshachi.ddo.jp/blog/comp/archives/000799.html